# Suggestions for auto confirming MS SQL 2005 data entry in a build process

Tags: sql-server-2005, visual-build-professional

I have a automated (Visual Build) build process that runs:

A set of automated smoke tests (AutoIT) that enters data into a .Net WinForm app that writes to a cleanly seeded MS SQL 2005 DB.

A SQL query that returns the data I want.

```
SELECT i.ID, i.firstname, i.lastname, i.ModDate
FROM app.Individual i
Where lastname = 'Doe'
```

Now what I would like to do is confirm:

The number of rows returned (let's say should be 1)

The value of i.ID, i.firstname, i.lastname (let's say should be 1, John, Doe)

ModDate is today

The values of what the data should be can be pulled from a CSV file. VisualBuild can launch external applications, so the limitation there is just Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The automation tool TestComplete does this well: http://www.automatedqa.com/products/testcomplete/

Answer (score 0):

So, why don't you use NUnit tests project to be with build right after main project testing?
You can easily test SQL data for assertion there.